# how to use Javascript foreach loop with associative array object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

i have below given array as my ajax response, now i want to append these array values in my html div for this i have used for loop but whats going wrong ? i am getting below output (see attached image)

```
//Array from php page
Array ( 
[FirstName] => Please enter your first name 
[LastName] => Please enter last name 
[Email] => This e-mail address is already associated to another account. 
[ConfirmPassword] => Passwords do not match 
)

//jquery
success:function(result){
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
{
  console.log(result[i]);
  $("#error_div").append(result[i]);
}
  }

//want this output to append in div
Please enter your first name 
Please enter last name 
This e-mail address is already associated to another account.
Passwords do not match
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There is no associative array in javascript, it's a just an object with properties.

If you would like to iterate this object you can use a `for...in` loop:

```
for (var key in result) 
{
  console.log(result[key]);
  $("#error_div").append(result[key]);
}
```

You can also use a `for...of` loop with `Object.values()` to get the value directly:

```
for (let value of Object.values(result)) 
{
  console.log(value);
  $("#error_div").append(value);
}
```

Comment: Or `for(let key of Object.keys(obj))`.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has no associative arrays. You could loop over the object, but since you are using jQuery anyway you could use `each()`. If performance matters, use a for loop tho.

```
var values = {
    'FirstName': 'Please enter your first name ',
    'LastName': 'Please enter last name ',
    'Email': 'This e-mail address is already associated to another account. ',
    'ConfirmPassword' : 'Passwords do not match '
};

var errors = $('#error_div');
$.each(values, function( index, value ) {
  errors.append(value);
  errors.append('<br>');
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/662ud09c/1/)**

Comment: it's not working , see the attached image in my question, after using your answer i got that.